# Google API - Retrieving ResourceID?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, google-api

How do I retrieve a resourceid of a specified folder within GoogleDocs using C#? I understand I can retrieve it based on a file I have uploaded like below:

```
DocumentEntry docEntry = docServ.UploadDocument(@"c:\AnotherDocument1.txt", null);
Document newDoc = docReq.Retrieve<Document>(new Uri(docReq.BaseUri + "/" + docEntry.ResourceId));
string x = newDoc.ResourceId;
```

But I have a folder called "ABC" and I would like to get the ResourceId of this based on the name of this folder. I will be using this to move the document into the "ABC" folder.